# Spyder IDE adding development environment to path, not sure why / how to stop

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have a python 3 anaconda install with an additional development environment. When I launch from a terminal, I'm finding that Spyder is not just adopting the PATH variable from the terminal, but is instead pre-pending some values.

My pythonpath manager is empty.

My preferences > console>advanced settings is set to Default.

When I echo my path in terminal before launching spyder, it looks fine.

```
 /Users/Nick/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
```

When I type "which python" in terminal before launching it looks fine.

```
/Users/Nick/anaconda/bin/python
```

But in spyder, when I run print(sys.path) I find my github development folder pre-pended.

```
['', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython-0.22.1-py3.4-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg', '/Users/Nick/github/pandas', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python34.zip', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py3.4.egg', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-18.0.1-py3.4.egg', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aeosa', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/Nick/.ipython']
```

Any idea how to stop this?

Thanks!

Nick

Comment: OK, not Spyder, anaconda and site.py. See here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670985/python-adding-lots-of-things-to-path-how-do-i-stop/32671007