# Python adding lots of things to PATH. How do I stop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm finding that python is modifying my path in problematic ways -- in particular, it's pre-pending the path to my github development folder, which results in the wrong libraries being loaded.

In my terminal session, if I run `echo $PATH` I get:

```
~$echo $PATH
/Users/Nick/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:
/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
```

Which is perfect. But when I launch python from that same terminal session (either as `python` or `ipython`) and check my PATH from within python, I'm getting:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython-0.22.1-py3.4-
macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg', '/Users/Nick/github/pandas', 
'/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python34.zip', '/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4',     
'/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', 
'/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', 
'/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages', 
'/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py3.4.egg',
'/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aeosa', 
'/Users/Nick/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-18.0.1-py3.4.egg']
```

Where are these coming from and how do I stop them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PATH` has nothing to do with the Python module search path; that environment variable is used by your *shell* to find executables, instead.

You need to look at the [`PYTHONPATH` variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) here.

If that variable doesn't contain your extra elements, start Python with the [`-S` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-S) to disable loading `site.py`; it may be that the extra elements are set by a `.pth` file. Also see the [`site` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html):

> A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form `name.pth` and exists in one of the four directories mentioned above; its contents are additional items (one per line) to be added to `sys.path`.

Comment: a ha, thanks Martijn! Any advice on managing PYTHONPATH and dev environments in anaconda?

Comment: @nick_eu: I believe the `conda` command lets you create virtual environments; but I haven't really used Anaconda myself.

Comment: `conda create -n py2k python=2 anaconda` or `conda create -n py3k python=3 anaconda` will create a virtual environment that you can access via `source activate py2k` or `source activate py3k`  [run `conda update conda` and `conda update anaconda` first] to exit the virtual env, execute `source deactivate`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Huh -- that's what I've been doing, and why I was surprised this happened. It seems to work for my PATH var, but (apparently) not my python path...

Comment: @nick_eu: your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is not managed by a virtualenv. Clear the variable and leave managing the libraries on your path with the virtualenv instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Last followup: Where IS pythonpath being set? if I do `echo $PYTHONPATH` in my terminal I don't get anything...

Comment: @nick_eu: Then it is not your PYTHONPATH that is at fault here. Next stop: reading the `site` module documentation and looking for those `.pth` files.

Comment: Yup, the -S trick fixes the problem. Now to hunt down the .pth files in the anaconda installation. @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 3):

While `$PATH` seems like it may be used by Python, what you actually want to look at is your `$PYTHONPATH` -- which is used by the import machinery and logic.

You should look into [using `virtualenv`ironments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to control the pathing of Python module lookups.